# Dynamcially retrieve absolute path for package directory

Tags: python, import, module

I looking how to properly import a module from a package directory which works when using the command line. For example I have a module called `someapp.py` which has the a single line:

```
from project.resources import somemodule
```

My project directory and package structure is:

```
~/PycharmProject/myapp
myapp
|--project
   |--apps
   |  |--someapp.py
   |  |--__init__.py
   |--reources
   |  |--somemodule.py
   |  |--__init__.py
   |--__init__.py
```

If I run the `someapp.py` module using the pycharm IDE the module is `import`ed successfully.

```
/Users/rdediana/PycharmProjects/myapp/venv/bin/python /Users/rdediana/PycharmProjects/myapp/project/apps/someapp.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, if run the `someapp.py` module from the Mac Terminal I get the following error:

```
(venv) rdediana$ python3 someapp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "someapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project.resources import somemodule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

From my understanding, I need to add the `resources` directory to the `sys.path` to allow python to properly find and import `somemodule.py`.

**If this is the right approach, how can I dynamically retrieve the absolute path to the `resources` directory below?**

```
/Users/rdediana/PycharProjects/myapp/project/resources
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.` at front? I.e. like `from .project.resources import <whatever>`

Comment: thanks rv.
when i added the "." pycham complained about "Unresolved reference Project...."